# Dual Citzen returning to the UK after 20 years can I claim being a resident from day one?

Tags: united-kingdom, residency

I was born in the UK, I a dual citizen UK/Australian returning to the UK after 20 years. I have a NI number, and will be drawing government OAP next year. Am I deemed a resident of the UK from day one of arrival?

Comment: Deemed a resident for what purpose? The answer is different for different purposes.  For driver licensing, for example, the answer is no. For taxation, the answer probably depends on when you move relative to the tax year. And so on.

Comment: Are returning to the UK to live permanently? Or is there another specific reason?

Comment: @ouflak intent is a factor in determining domicile, but not in determining residency. The two are distinct.

Comment: @phoog, Agreed. I'm just not sure if the OP is worried about NHS access or something along those lines, in which case intent seems to be rather more important.

Answer (score 3):

It does depend, as phoog said, on what aspect of residency.

Generally speaking, you need to be in the UK for 6 months before being considered a resident. For example, you are NOT entitled to free NHS care for the first 6 months, so avoid mentioning your recent arrival to your doctor.

Tax is complicated, very complicated, More information is at http://tools.hmrc.gov.uk/rift/screen/SRT+-+Combined/en-GB/summary?user=guest

For opening bank accounts etc, you'll need a recent proof of address, but they won't check that you've been there for more than 6 months.

Comment: The OP just might be eligible for NHS access from day 1 in the UK, **if** he can demonstrate that he is returning to stay permanently. I'm just not sure how (of if) the NHS goes about making the distinction. Atleast that's my understanding of the wording of 'Normally Resident'.

Comment: @ouflak That's a valid point. The problem for the OP would be how his individual circumstances would be interpreted, and by whom.